# How to use a different graphic for a marker

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

I am showing different layers to show points on a map, see https://www.corobori.com/sos/TestMap3.html.

My customer would like to see a more traditional marker.

Below is my code showing the blue circle

```
var layer1 = new ol.layer.Vector
        (
        {
            source: new ol.source.Vector(
                {
                    features: [new ol.Feature(
                        {
                            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-71.4155802, -36.9046117]))
                        }
                    )]
                })
        }
        );
```

What should I change to use an external png file instead of the circle ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the style option inside the ol.layer.Vector like this:

```js
let vector = new ol.vector.Layer({
        source: source,
        features: youFeatures,
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)'
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#343434',
                width: 2
            }),
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 4,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(28,255,43,0.82)'
                })
            })
        })
    });
```

so you can specify the stroke and the fill of the features that you will draw and in the `image` option you can specify the style of the points.

You can also use a custom icon an change the `image` option like in [this example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/custom-interactions.html?q=custom)

```js
image: new Icon(/** @type {module:ol/style/Icon~Options} */ ({
                anchor: [0.5, 46],
                anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                opacity: 0.95,
                src: 'data/icon.png'
              }))
```

Comment: I am trying the 2nd way as in the sample.

but at
style: new ol.Style({image: new ol.Style.Icon(/** @type {module:ol/style/Icon~Options} */({

I am getting
TestMap3.html:123 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Icon' of undefined

The sample is here: https://www.corobori.com/sos/TestMap3.html

Comment: I keep fighting on this. changed to style: new ol.style({image: new ol.style.Icon(({ and I am getting TestMap3.html:122 Uncaught TypeError: ol.style is not a constructor

Comment: Sorry, I just changed `ol.Style` in `ol.style.Style`. 
And for the Icon, as in the note you should use `ol.style.Icon`

Comment: Updated, now the error doesn't come up but I am still seeing the point and I don't see the style being applied.

Comment: if you are using the Icon have you changed the src path with the path of your logo?

Comment: I tried both   src: '/map-marker3.png' or   src: 'map-marker3.png' but none seems to work.

Comment: ok at the beginning of the code do: `import logoImage from 'yourPath' ` and then put logoImage in the src option. I have tried and in this way it works

Comment: Got it working ! The issue was how I applied the style to the feature.  


 var layer1 = new ol.layer.Vector
 ({
                source: new ol.source.Vector({
                        features: [new ol.Feature({
                            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-71.4155802, -36.9046117]))}
                        )]
                }),style:pStyle
            }); 
        map.addLayer(layer1);

Comment: I uploaded a fiddle if it can help somebody interested about that: https://jsfiddle.net/Corobori/zs9kvd1e/